# How do I debug the errors from the AJAX response while trying to delete folder using controller method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete folders when user clicks on the delete button in the front end. This is the function which recursively empties files and then deletes the directory:

**php**

```
function deleteFiles($target){
    if(is_dir($target)){
    $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned

    foreach( $files as $file ){
        deleteFiles( $file );      
    }
    rmdir( $target );
    }elseif(is_file($target)) {
        unlink( $target );  
    }
}
```

The above function does its job but throws some warnings like 'Permission denied' and 'No such directory found' but yet deletes the directory anyway. The Problem lies in the AJAX call, here is the code:

**javascript**

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/course-elearn/coursepaysapp/sections/delete_section_activity',
    data: {section_name: section_name},
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result){
    alert(result);
    },
    error: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

The above call is working but executing the error function in AJAX and responding with 'Object object' and is not even deleting the directory, I'm confused and unable to debug because the request is being made through AJAX and I'm not able to retrieve the errors.

Comment: The crux of the matter is that PHP will always return a 200 status, even if the script fails. You will want to report an error just like you report a success within your PHP and then look for this in your AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

**PHP**

```
function deleteFile($f){
  $r = array("result" => "error", "message" => "");
  try {
    unlink($f);
    $r['result'] = success;
    $r['message'] = "$f deleted.";
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    $r['message'] = $e->getMessage();
  }
  return $r;
}

function deleteFiles($target){
  $result = array(
    "result" => "",
    "message" => ""
  );
  try {
    if(is_dir($target)) {
      $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); 
      foreach( $files as $file ){
        deleteFile($file);      
      }
      rmdir($target);
      $result['result'] = "success";
      $result['message'] = "$target was removed."
    } elseif(is_file($target)) {
      $result = deleteFile($target);
    }
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    $result['result'] = "error";
    $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
$results = deleteFiles($_GET['section_name']);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
```

In your JavaScript, you will not send the request and get a response that can be interpreted.

**JavaScript**

```
$.getJSON("/course-elearn/coursepaysapp/sections/delete_section_activity", { section_name: section_name }, function(r){
  if(r.result == "success"){
    console.log(r.message);
  } else {
    alert("Error: " + r.message);
  }
});
```